# Why does ?: cause a conversion error while if-else does not?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

Making some changes in the code I use the next line:

```
uint a = b == c ? 0 : 1;
```

Visual Studio shows me this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'uint'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

But if I use the code:

```
uint a; 

if (b == c) 
    a = 0; 
else 
    a = 1;
```

It works correctly without any error or warning. Why?

Comment: `(b == c) ? 0U : 1U` would work. It's due to implicit conversion which happens with integer literals when being assigned directly to a variable. But when you're using the ternary operator, compiler doesn't do the implicit conversion and only checks if both branches can be converted to the same type.

Comment: The conditional operator is not an `if...else`, other rules.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, But logically the ?: operator implies a if..else. Would be interesting to see how it translates in the IL.

Comment: Actually, `... ? 0U : 1` (or `... ? 0 : 1U`) should also work correctly, the compiler should give the `uint` type to the whole expression.

Comment: I agree with you @Thangadurai. I had suppose that the compiler translate the ternary operator to an if-else when compile it.

Comment: There is a difference between a constant expression and a non-constant expression. The compiler is able to do more conversions with the former than the latter, and your examples involve the latter when using the ternary operator and the former when not. See marked duplicate and it's marked duplicate for more details.

Comment: @Ruben: both of them will most likely be compiled into the same assembly in the end, but the compiler still has to follow conversion rules. You can basically think of it as `var tmp =  (b == c) ? 1 : 0;` (type of `tmp` is inferred), and then `uint a = tmp;` in the next line.

Comment: There are two options to solve problem of assigning result of `?:` operator: 1) ensure **both** branches will return expected type (e.g. by casting them individually or using suffixes for constants) 2) ensure what **result** of `?:` is of expected type by casting it: `var a = (uint)(condition ? type : type)` (error message clearly states this cast is required).

Comment: Actually the assembly looks different. The ternary operator does not have a jump at all. [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/GX9WSk) Sadly I'm not fluent enough in assembly to actually understand the ´movzx´

Comment: A better way to avoid this problem is to not use uint in the first place. Why are you using uint? This is a bad code smell in C#. uint is there for interoperability with C and COM libraries that use uint.

Comment: Another solution would be: `uint a = Convert.ToUInt32(b != c);`

Comment: @EricLippert why is uint a bad code smell? If you have a value that should never be negative and you need a higher upper limit but don't want to allocate more memory, then wouldn't using this be considered an optimisation? Implementing your own check to keep from falling below 0 would just introduce unnecessary logic. Just curious is all ...

Comment: @JakeMillington: I said why it is a bad code smell. It is there for *interoperability with COM*. You'll note that `string.Length` is never negative, but is not a uint. Neither is `List.Count`. Being non-negative is insufficient reason to use `uint`.  I submit to you that an *optimization* should be justified by *data*; is there a program in the marketplace whose success or failure is gated on the choice of whether to use `uint` or `long`?

Comment: @JakeMillington: Moreover, if you have a quantity that is routinely over two billion, then *use a long for heaven's sake*.  Do you really want to spend even a single minute debugging the problem when the quantity you thought would always be less than four billion is suddenly five billion, and the uint wraps?

Comment: @JakeMillington: But wait, there's more.  Let's suppose we have two quantities that are logically never negative. The size of a string, say.  OK, I mote it so: `string.Length` is now `uint`. Now please write for me correctly the code that takes two strings and gives me the difference in their lengths.  How often do you think you'd forget to add the cast to int? How long do you think it would take for that bug to cause a serious failure? And now we'd have a program whose failure in the marketplace is due to use of uint! **uints do not match the mathematical domain in which we routinely work.**

Comment: @EricLippert Point taken. I was under the impression that allocating the extra memory for a long was a bad thing if a larger portion of it would stay untouched. Thanks for that explanation. Still learning here ....

Comment: @JakeMillington: A long is eight bytes. An int is four. You have at a minimum TWO BILLION bytes of address space. Do you have more than say a hundred million longs?  If so, start worrying about it then. You are a memory billionaire; don't worry about pennies.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

> Why can't I use `uint a = b == c ? 0 : 1;`?

The type of the expression `b == c ? 0 : 1` is `int`. As shown in [this table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx), there is no implicit conversion from `int` to `uint`, so this is not allowed.

> Why can I use `a = 0`?

Because there is special treatment of numeric types when the value is a constant expression.

From section 6.1.9 of the C# specification:

> - A constant expression of type int can be converted to type sbyte, byte, short, ushort, uint, or ulong, provided the value of the constant-expression is within the range of the destination type.
> - A constant expression of type long can be converted to type ulong, provided the value of the constant expression is not negative.

As indicated in the first bullet `a = 0` and `a = 1` are both allowed because `0` and `1` are constant expressions and are valid `uint` values. Basically what this boils down to is that the compiler can easily determine at compile time that these conversions are valid, so it allows them.

Incidentally, if the `b == c` part of your first example were changed to a constant expression (e.g. `true`), then the whole conditional operator expression would be a constant expression and the code would compile.

Answer (score 26):

**If** `b==c` were a constant expression then the whole conditional operator would be considered a constant expression and so, then, the rule allowing constant expressions of type `int` to be converted to other int types would apply and it would compile.

Obviously, `b==c` is not a constant expression and so the result of the conditional operator cannot be known until runtime and so the exemption that allows an implicit conversion of ints to uint (for constant expressions) does not apply.

In your `if`/`else` variant, *both* of the actual assignments are constant expressions.

Comment: This explains why `uint a = true ? 0 : 1` *does* compile. The gist of it is that implicit conversion only applies for constant expressions.

Comment: @haim770 - that's why I decided to answer. Groo's comment, whilst being mostly sufficient, implied that the conditional operator could never allow this to work.

Answer (score 10):

You should use [literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx) to make your code work correctly like this:

```
uint a = b == c ? 0U : 1U;
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't answer OP's question.